# pythagorean formula to calculate the perimeter of triangle in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, pythagorean

i am so newbie in programming. i had problem how to count the area and around of triangle.

i had code code some, but the output results are always wrong calculate.

```js
function fungsiLuasSegitiga(a, b) {
  var luas = (1 / 2) * a * b;
  return luas;
}

function fungsiKllSegitiga(a, b) {
  var c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
  var kll = a + b + c;
  return kll;
}

var x = prompt("masukkan nilai alas segitiga!");
var y = prompt("masukkan nilai tinggi segitiga!");

var d = fungsiLuasSegitiga(x, y);
var e = fungsiKllSegitiga(x, y);

alert("luas segitiga adalah " + d);
alert("keliling segitiga adalah " + e);
```

when i put number 3 and 4, the function fungsiLuasSegitiga count it be 345, but the result must be 12 (3+4+5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#Syntax) returns a string and not a number. So, `kll` calculation ends up being `"3" + "4" + 5`. This concatenates the string instead of summing the numbers. You need to parse it to a number before assigning it to `x` and `y` either by using [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) or [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
function fungsiLuasSegitiga(a, b) {
  var luas = (1 / 2) * a * b;
  return luas;
}

function fungsiKllSegitiga(a, b) {
  var c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
  var kll = a + b + c;
  return kll;
}

var x = +prompt("masukkan nilai alas segitiga!");
var y = +prompt("masukkan nilai tinggi segitiga!");

var d = fungsiLuasSegitiga(x, y);
var e = fungsiKllSegitiga(x, y);

alert("luas segitiga adalah " + d);
alert("keliling segitiga adalah " + e);
```